# Query regarding VLookUp

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vlookup

I have the following table:

| Name | Parameter | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | Param 1 | 10 |
| Jack | Param 2 | 20 |
| Jack | Param 3 | 30 |
| Roy | Param 1 | 40 |
| Roy | Param 2 | 50 |
| Roy | Param 3 | 60 |

What I want to do is this:

| Name | Param 1 | Param 2 | Param 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| Roy | 40 | 50 | 60 |

I tried VLookUp, but I am not able to get the desired result. Can someone help me with this?

[Image is about the table, which is messed up in the description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNTsl.png)

Comment: This is typically done through a pivot table.

Answer (score 2):

It's a job for QUERY formula or for pivot table.

Assuming that your data is in columns form B to D you can use this:

```
=query(B2:D8,"select B, sum(D) group by B PIVOT C ")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the revert. Your solution worked in one of my sheets. But the other sheet shows this error: 

Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tried googling, but none of the solutions work. Any idea how I can work around this error.
Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: Strange. I don;t know. I'd have to see the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Office 365, this can be done by using sumifs function. Suppose that you have
[image]

You only need 3 formulas in cells E2, F1, and F2 as follows:
[image]